# Block PictureBox to receive events C#

Tags: c#, events, picturebox

i hope you will help me :))
i want to Block/Enable PictureBox to receive events, i cant do myself, plase help me :)
thans beforehand :*

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the `PictureBox`:

```
PictureBox1.Enabled = false; // Will not fire any events
PictureBox1.Enabled = true; // Will now fire events
```

While it's disabled, it will not cause any events to fire. There's no way to stop other events changing the PictureBox's properties though, unless you create your own class inheriting from the PictureBox and override/hide all the other properties/method calls.